# can not get api/mail

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman

Not sure why but when I make get requests to api using Postman, it is not working. Here is my attempt:

**myfolder/routes/api/mail.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get(
  "/",
  (req, res) => {
   console.log("get is working")
  }
);
module.exports = router;
```

**myfolder/server.js**

```
const mail = require("./routes/api/mail");
const app = express();
app.use("/api/mail", mail);
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server up and running on port ${port} !`));
```

On Postman I am making a GET request to `localhost:5000/api/mail`

Answer (score 0):

I'm no express expert, but I think you're not actually sending anything back in `mail.js`, all you're doing is logging to the console...

try adding this line just before you log to console.

> res.status(200).send('some text')